# How to create a pivot table with related field other than id on Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, pivot, relation

I want to create (on Laravel 5.2) a pivot between two entities, let's assume that we have the entities User and Phone. In our world, a user can have several phones, and te phones can have several owners.

For a reason, I must target the user's phone by it's serial number and the build year (let's assume that serials can't be identical on a same year).

So I have my tables `users`, `phones` and`users_phones`.

```
===== Table users =====
id
username
...

===== Table phones ====
id
serial_numer
build_year

===== Table users_phones ====
user_id
phone_serial
phone_build_year
```

I have my relation on my model Phone :

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
            User::class,
            'users_phones',
            'user_id',
            'phone_serial'
        )->withPivot('phone_build_year');
}
```

When I wan't to add some entries like that :

```
$phone->users()->attach([$user->id => [
    'phone_build_year'  => $phone->build_year
]]);
```

The SQL request generated is the following one :

```
insert into `users_phones` (`user_id`, `phone_serial`, `phone_build_year`) values (1, 5, 2016)
```

My problem is that the `5` in the sql request is the phone id and not its serial. I didn't find how to precise to Laravel to use the field we chose (here the serial) rather than the id.

Is it possible to do that, or am I condemned to create a model to manipulate my special pivot table ? I admit that I would appreciate if I could avoid that way.

Comment: Laravel doesn't let you do that - it only allows `primary key` of the related models for `belongsToMany`. You can either use additional model for the pivot table or create custom implementation on `BelongsToMany` relation.

Comment: That's what I thought, too bad ! Thanx for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as Jarek says, it seems that there is no way to customize the Laravel pivot relations as I would like to do. I will create a model dedicated to this particular case.
Anyway, if someone has a better and elegant way to do this kind of custom pivot relation on Laravel, please share your knowledge !